# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS crashed and won't boot, boot-repair didn't fix it

Tags: boot, 20.04

good people, I'm having a little trouble.
I'm not a complete tool, but I'm definitely on the beginner side of computing.
Built my desktop in May (AMD Ryzen 3 3200G, Gigabyte B450M DS3) and been running Ubuntu Studio as the only OS without much trouble at all.

Today I was plugging a usb lamp in the back of my machine and when I got back up to the desk, my screen was blank and all was dead.
Since then, I can't boot the OS and even when I press escape to get to Grub, I can't edit it and only see lines with "grub>" or something similar.
I booted the system from my bootable usb stick ("try without installation") - I can only do it in safe graphics mode.
There are few errors appearing:

- Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
- pci: 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
- [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modeset
- sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
- sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through

In the safe mode (running from the usb stick), I tried boot-repair, which didn't work.
This is the generated pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4vQttQtWc2/

I managed to save some important data on the harddrive on the cloud, so I'm ready to reinstall the OS and start from scratch, but is there anything else I could do before being this radical?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The BootRepair tool doesn't seem to be the right way to fix a "crash". I am also not sure a reinstall will help, given the USB can't boot properly. From what you've told, the problem might be hardware related.

Comment: Seeing the problem started same time as plugging in the USB lamp, would test lamp for shorts or anything.  Might of fried something inside.

Comment: I reinstalled the system (wiped out the disc) and still the same. Ran a hard drive test from the stick via gnome disk utility and came out clear. I only have the mobo and CPU with integrated graphics in the computer. Is there a way how I can check out those for a fault?